# express 405 method not allowed using local ip address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It's ok when using http://localhost:8090, but not worked when I input http://192.168.74.128:8090.
[image]
[image]
here is ip address 
[image]

here is my code, use mac os:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello, rcc')
})

app.listen(8090, ()=>{
    console.log('server\'s OK')
})
```

anyone can help?thanks

[image]

Comment: works fine for me (node 8.2.1 - win64) are you sure that's the right IP address? Perhaps there's some firewall (what OS?)

Comment: @JaromandaX using OSX, and I edit my question

Comment: Are you using some sort of firewall or antivirus software, or a proxy server?

Comment: @robertklep none of these

Comment: Can you add the output of the following command to your question: `curl -vI http://192.168.74.128:8090`

Comment: Is there a second node process running in the background that is responding to this request instead?

Comment: @robertklep I add the output at the end of the question

Comment: are you sending a get to a post, etc...

Comment: @JeffBreadner no other node process is running, but I find other application process is using this port also, I kill it, and it's worked.